# ASP.NET exception gives irrelevant stack trace on YSOD, very challenging!

Tags: c#, asp.net, stack-trace, spring.net

Here is the YSOD:

Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Source Error: 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.]
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +428
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +65
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +117
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +122
   ECommerce.PMethod.Sql.SqlConns.Open() +78
   ECommerce.PMethod.Sql.SqlConns..ctor() +120
   ECommerce.login.DatasInfo.Proc.UserCenter.IsLogin(String UserGUID, Int32 UserID) +49
   ECommerce.login.Rules.Users.UserLogin.isLogin() +44
   Config.isUserLogined() +5
   Shopping_Shopping.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +10
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'ECommerce.ERP.DAL.DBConn' threw an exception.]
   ECommerce.ERP.DAL.DBConn.get_ConnString() +0

[ObjectDefinitionStoreException: Factory method 'System.String get_ConnString()' threw an Exception.]
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.Instantiate(RootObjectDefinition definition, String name, IObjectFactory factory, MethodInfo factoryMethod, Object[] arguments) +257
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.ConstructorResolver.InstantiateUsingFactoryMethod(String name, RootObjectDefinition definition, Object[] arguments) +624
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.InstantiateUsingFactoryMethod(String name, RootObjectDefinition definition, Object[] arguments) +60
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.CreateObjectInstance(String objectName, RootObjectDefinition objectDefinition, Object[] arguments) +56
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.InstantiateObject(String name, RootObjectDefinition definition, Object[] arguments, Boolean allowEagerCaching, Boolean suppressConfigure) +436

[ObjectCreationException: Error thrown by a dependency of object 'styleService' defined in 'assembly [ECommerce.Services.Impl, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null], resource [ECommerce.Services.Impl.AppContext.xml] line 56' : Initialization of object failed : Factory method 'System.String get_ConnString()' threw an Exception.
while resolving 'constructor argument with name promotionservice' to 'promotionService' defined in 'assembly [ECommerce.Services.Impl, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null], resource [ECommerce.Services.Impl.AppContext.xml] line 31'
while resolving 'constructor argument with name domainservice' to 'promotionDomainService' defined in 'assembly [ECommerce.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null], resource [ECommerce.Domain.AppContext.xml] line 20'
while resolving 'constructor argument with name promotionrepos' to 'promotionRepos' defined in 'assembly [ECommerce.Data.AdoNet, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null], resource [ECommerce.Data.AdoNet.AppContext.xml] line 34'
while resolving 'constructor argument with name connstr' to 'ECommerce.ERP.DAL.DBConn#389F399' defined in 'assembly [ECommerce.Data.AdoNet, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null], resource [ECommerce.Data.AdoNet.AppContext.xml] line 34']
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.ObjectDefinitionValueResolver.ResolveReference(IObjectDefinition definition, String name, String argumentName, RuntimeObjectReference reference) +394
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.ObjectDefinitionValueResolver.ResolvePropertyValue(String name, IObjectDefinition definition, String argumentName, Object argumentValue) +312
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.ObjectDefinitionValueResolver.ResolveValueIfNecessary(String name, IObjectDefinition definition, String argumentName, Object argumentValue) +17
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.ConstructorResolver.ResolveConstructorArguments(String objectName, RootObjectDefinition definition, ObjectWrapper wrapper, ConstructorArgumentValues cargs, ConstructorArgumentValues resolvedValues) +993
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.ConstructorResolver.AutowireConstructor(String objectName, RootObjectDefinition rod, ConstructorInfo[] chosenCtors, Object[] explicitArgs) +171
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.AutowireConstructor(String name, RootObjectDefinition definition, ConstructorInfo[] ctors, Object[] explicitArgs) +65
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.CreateObjectInstance(String objectName, RootObjectDefinition objectDefinition, Object[] arguments) +161
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.InstantiateObject(String name, RootObjectDefinition definition, Object[] arguments, Boolean allowEagerCaching, Boolean suppressConfigure) +636
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractObjectFactory.CreateAndCacheSingletonInstance(String objectName, RootObjectDefinition objectDefinition, Object[] arguments) +174
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.WebObjectFactory.CreateAndCacheSingletonInstance(String objectName, RootObjectDefinition objectDefinition, Object[] arguments) +150
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractObjectFactory.GetObjectInternal(String name, Type requiredType, Object[] arguments, Boolean suppressConfigure) +990
   Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractObjectFactory.GetObject(String name) +10
   Spring.Context.Support.AbstractApplicationContext.GetObject(String name) +20
   ECommerce.Common.ServiceLocator.GetService() +334
   ECommerce.Mvc.Controllers.StylesController..ctor() +72

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean fillCache) +86
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean fillCache) +230
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +67
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +80

[InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'ECommerce.Mvc.Controllers.StylesController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +190
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +68
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +118
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +46
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +63
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +13
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8677954
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3082; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3082

Question is: the first stack trace is irrelevant to others, what happened? Any ideas?

Let me make this more clear:

a MVC page uses the spring part trying to load a lazy-init service which constructor wants a connection string through a static property like this:

```
<object id="promotionRepos" type="ECommerce.Data.AdoNet.Promotions.PromotionRepos, ECommerce.Data.AdoNet" lazy-init="true">
    <constructor-arg name="provider">
        <null />
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg name="connStr">
        <object type="ECommerce.ERP.DAL.DBConn, ECommerce.ERP.DAL" factory-method="get_ConnString" />
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="RefreshInterval" value="00:00:10" />
</object>
```

the timeout part is some what irrelevent to all others. see this in the first exception: Shopping_Shopping.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +10 
it's another page at all. And also, ECommerce.PMethod.Sql.SqlConns.Open() uses its own connection string, not the one loaded by spring, it's different module from diffrent team. And I am sure the connection string is correct.

And, this ysod cames up randomly. Sometimes nothing is wrong, and sometimes, it appears.

I thought there could be something wrong with my database or the network/firewall, I will check it later, but now I want understand this tricky stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like they are all relevant. They seem to be to do with instantiating objects using Spring.Net. Ultimately it looks like your database server is either not responding or your connection string is completely wrong.

Can you access the database using the DB managemnet software that you use?

Comment: sorry for my bad explanation, I made the question more clearly, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing that your connection string is wrong or the database server is not turned on when your application tries to connect to the database. Double check your connection string.

Comment: sorry for my bad explanation, I made the question more clearly, please help.